# Salesforce api v28 not rendering css classes when rendering pdf

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I'm creating a Visualforce page rendered as a pdf ( `renderAs="pdf"` ), and the page won't render any of my CSS styling.  I am wrapping my `<style>` with `<head>` as shown below.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" readOnly="true" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" renderAs="pdf">
    <head>
        <style>
            @page{
                margin:1in;
            }
            .myTable {
                border-collapse:collapse;
                border:1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <table class="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td>A Column</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</apex:page>
```

What's really bizarre is that I tried copying another VF page that I have rendered as a PDF with style classes and the like, and **IT** won't render either.  So I thought, "What if I change the API version of my VF page to 27?"  And lo, it works.

Any ideas on fixing this to work with API v28?  Or is this just a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2013/06/using-css-in-pdf-for-page-numbering.html

I have documented behaviour in the above blogpost.

Applyhtml=false has to be manually set to false in apex:page to get this working.This is a new attribute added in API 28.0